# excel charts not accepting date-time series in x axis

Tags: excel

How to make excel accept the following as different data points on the x-axis.

```
    Time                Licenses Used
    2013-07-09 11:34    512
    2013-07-09 11:36    523
    2013-07-09 11:40    621
    2013-07-09 11:43    125
    2013-07-10 09:30    526
    2013-07-10 10:30    589
    2013-07-10 11:30    546
    2013-07-11 10:40    549
```

Why does Excel charts club all the times on a date together, why cant it interpret it a different time entries?

Comment: Are your dates numbers formated as dates or are they just text?

Comment: there were date formats itself.

Comment: Convert the column into numbers and plot it as numbers. Then format the x-axis as Date format.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you are using a line chart, change to an XY scatter chart with lines instead; a date axis on a line chart will ignore the time portion

Answer (score 5):

There is one way to do this. To make the x-axis consider the values as text.

> > in Excel 2007, click on the chart - Go to the layout menu (contextual menu on clicking on the chart) , choose the option **Axes->Primary Horizontal Axes-> More Horizontal Axes Options**
> >     Under **Axis Type**, choose "**Text Axis**"

[image]

Comment: This plots the items as separate categories, but not proportionally to their inherent values. For that you need to use an XY Scatter chart.